# How to install python build dependencies via python3-pip-native on Yocto

Tags: python, pip, yocto, bitbake, requirements.txt

I needed to build binary that requires tons of python packages. I succeeded, but I needed to install all packages manually on my build machine via pip. This is very nasty solution that I would like to redo with usage of native tools. But I found myself unable to do so. My idea is that the user shouldn't bother themselves about any python package at all and the installation should be managed fully via `python3-pip-native`. However, calling `python3 -m pip install -r ${S}/scripts/constraints.txt` in `do_cofigure()` on a brand new build system results in errors:

```
| Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
| WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f26123a4a60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/anytree/
| WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f26123a4d90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/anytree/
| WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f26123a4f40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/anytree/
| WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f26123a50f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/anytree/
| WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f26123a52a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/anytree/
| ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anytree==2.8.0 (from versions: none)
| ERROR: No matching distribution found for anytree==2.8.0
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
```

How do I properly install build dependencies via python3-pip-native?

Please note that none of the packages are needed at runtime.